# Will Linux programs crash if there is enough ram but not enough virtual memory？

Tags: linux, memory, embedded-linux, ram, virtual-memory

For example, I run the top command and see that my application uses 1MB RES and 1000MB VIRT. Will this program crash if my system just has 128MB RAM and 512MB virtual memory?

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough ram, you don't actually need any virtual memory.  The only time virtual memory is used is... when you run out of actual memory.
The system writes some ram to virtual memory(disk), and then uses that memory for something else... loading that virtual memory back into actual memory only when it is needed (and that may require writing some other memory to virtual memory to free some memory up for that).
Depending on how the system is configured, it can tell you that it allocated memory for you... but if you never touched it, it never really allocated that memory for you (real or virtual).
So... **if your program is actually using 1MB RES + 1000MB VIRT** it could not fit into less than 1001MB memory (virtual or real), but if the system over-promised the memory and never really allocated for you.. then your program could run until it actually uses enough memory to run out of memory.